# Using Neo4j and Lucene in a distributed system

Tags: solr, neo4j, lucene

I am looking into Neo4j as a stripped-down document store.  A key aspect of document storage is search, and I know Neo4j includes full text search via legacy indices provided by Lucene.

I would be very interested in hearing the limitations of Neo4j search capabilities in a distributed environment.  Does it provide a distributed index?  In what ways is it inferior to Solr or ElasticSearch?  How far can I take it before I must install Solr?

-- EDIT --

We are trying to integrate two distinct search efforts.  The first is standard text content search.  For instance, using the Enron emails, we want to search for every email that matches "bananas" or "going to the store" and get those document bodies in response.  This is where people often turn to Solr.

The second case is more complicated, we have attached a great deal of meta-data to each document.  We may have decided that "these" emails were the result of late-night drunk-dialing.  Now I want to search for all emails that may have been the result of late-night drunk-dialing.  For this kind of meta-data, we believe a graph database is in order.

In a perfect world, I can use one platform to perform both queries.  I appreciate that Neo4j (nor OrientDB, Arango, etc) are designed as full text search databases, but I'm trying to understand the limitations thereof.

In terms of volume, we are dealing at a very large scale with batch-style nightly updates.  The data is content heavy, with some documents running into hundreds of pages of text, but mostly on the order of a page or two.

Comment: Can you give some more examples of what you want to search for?

Comment: In general in a Neo4j cluster you can search on every machine for the full index. What data sizes are you thinking about?

Comment: @MichaelHunger I just updated per your questions.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I once worked on a health social network where we needed some sort of search and connection search functionalities we first went on neo4j we were very impressed by the cypher query language we could get and express any request however when you throw there billion of nodes you start to pay the price and we started considering another graph db, this time we've made a lot of research, tests and OrientDB was clearly the winner, OrientDB is highly scalable but the thing is that you have to code by yourself, your "search algorithm" if you want to do some advanced things (what is the common point between this two nodes) otherwise you have the SQL like query language (i don't know/remember if he has a name) but you can do some interesting stuff with it 
So in conclusion i would definitely go on OrientDB

Comment: we have been looking at OrientDB as well.  It appears to have some really great features.  We can't afford a full bake-off, but I would love to hear more of what you guys learned, especially in search and managing documents.

Answer (score 0):

Neo4j can provide a "distributed index" in the sense that the [high availability cluster](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/ha-architecture.html) can make your index available on more than one machine, but I'm pretty sure that's not what you're after.  Related to this issue is a [different answer I wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31277849/neo4j-partition/31279781#31279781) about graph partitioning, and what it takes to distribute a really large number of nodes/relationships across multiple machines.  (It's not terribly simple)

Solr and Lucene do two different things (although Solr is built on top of Lucene).  I think solr and neo4j are not comparable because they're trying to do completely different things.  This site isn't about software recommendations so I can't tell you what you should use other than to say you should read up on solr and neo4j, and figure out which set of functionality you want.  As far as I know, this is an exclusive decision as I'm not aware of people integrating solr with neo4j.

Your question is very difficult to answer, I'd recommend expanding on what you are trying to do and what you have tried, you'll probably get better responses.

Comment: Thanks for that, but Neo4j provides very little information on the Lucene functionality.  I'm hoping some people have some specific experience doing basic text search within Neo4j.

Comment: I did, yes, and thanks. It doesn't speak to distributed data sets, though.  Do you know of anywhere I can get an honest evaluation of the search capabilities in practice?

Comment: Because neo4j is just wrapping lucene query syntax, I think evaluations of lucene apply to what neo4j can do for you.  I think solr is an entirely different ballpark.